# Recursively searching for specific filenames in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently using Python 3.x. I am looking to recursively search directories for two specific filenames. I know that each of the two filenames will exist in some of the directories. If one of the files exists, the other will. Once the files are identified, I then want to extract them to a list but somehow link them so that I can process them together later on as I'll want to extract data from each of the two files and analyse that data and then, do the same but for the same files from a different directory if that makes sense. So, in *C:\Desktop* and *C:\MyDocuments* for example, each directory will contain the two filenames I'm looking to identify (manifest.plist and info.plist)

So far, I have the following which searches based on the file extension and not on the filename:-

```
def find(pattern, path):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))

if __name__=='__main__':
    find("*.plist", test_path)
```

The exact filenames are *manifest.plist* and *info.plist*.

The above approach works well but it takes an age as it works through the thousands of files in each directory.

Is there a way to quickly look for the files based on their specific names and likewise, how am I best to link the two files from each directory in a list? I'm thinking of making *result[]* list to contain tuples with each tuple containing the paths to the respective *info.plist* and *manifest.plist*

Thanks all

Answer (score 5):

You should use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) module for that, specifically `glob.iglob(pathname, recursive=True)` for large directories.